# springSecurityService.principal.id giving firstname instead of userid

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am using springSecurityCore plugin in my application and after user login in the appStartupController, I do like

```
def index = {
   if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()) {
      session.loginId=springSecurityService.principal.id
      def userRole=UserRole.findAllByUserAndRole(User.get(session.loginId), Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_USERSDASH'))
      if(userRole){
         redirect(controller:'dashboard',action:'getRiskUserDashboard')
      }
   }
}
```

when I read session.loginId in the header.gsp I see the firstname from the User table is printed. 
I need to have the userId field in the User table mapped to the session.loginId.
How to do that?

Comment: not an answer, but you can check roles more simply by, SpringSecurityUtils.ifAllGranted('ROLE_USERSDASH')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the current User by calling the following:

```
def user = springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()
```

And then just pass that user into the UserRole find method.