# login from android http post to grails 3 spring security

Tags: android, spring, grails

i am trying to create an android application to do something with my database.

for example: i run my grails app on port 8080, `localhost:8080` then i use `POSTMAN` and pass paramter like this..

it success with like this..

[image]

but why i fail to login with my android application .

like this..

```
public static String  performPostCall(String requestURL,
            HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {
        Log.d("url = ",requestURL);
        URL url;
        String response = "";
        try {
            url = new URL(requestURL);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(45000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(45000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "form-data");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);


            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println(".toString() = "+responseCode);
            System.out.println(".HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK = "+HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK);
            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                String line;
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                    response+=line;
                }
            }
            else {
                response="";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }

    private static String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()){
            Log.d("entry.getKey() = ",entry.getKey());
            Log.d("entry.getValue() = ",entry.getValue());
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }
        System.out.println("tetstes = "+result.toString());
        return result.toString();
    }
```

then

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                 HashMap<String, String> parameter = new  HashMap<String, String>();
                 parameter.put("username", username);
                 parameter.put("password", password);

                try {
                    response = MyHttpURLConnection.performPostCall(URL, parameter); 
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("assdfdsf = "+e);
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
```

it always fail in `def ajaxSuccess` because i cannot get `SpringSecurityServyce.principal.id`
i tried to get `springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()` like this..

```
def ajaxSuccess() {
//      println "adf = "+springSecurityService.authentication.username
        println "cookies = "+session.id
        def cifus = springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()
        println "cifus = "+cifus
//      println "adf = "+springSecurityService.principal.id
        def user = com.vastpalaso.security.User.findByUsername(springSecurityService.authentication.name)
        def userDetails = com.vastpalaso.security.UserDetails.findByUser(user)
        def cifUser = corporateUserService.getCurrentCifUser()

        println "user = "+user
//      println "cif user = "+cifUser
//      println "cif user = "+cifUser.cif.corpName
//      if(cifUser){
//          session.setAttribute("company",cifUser.cif.corpName)
//          if(new Date() >cifUser.cif.expireDate ){
//              redirect(controller: "error", action: "serverError")
//          }
//      }
//
//      if (userDetails.isLogin.equals("1")) {
//          def sessionx = HttpSessionCollector.find(userDetails.sessionId)
//          if (sessionx) {
//              sessionx.invalidate()
//              HttpSessionCollector.remove(userDetails.sessionId)
//          }
//      }



        try {
            def ipAddress = request.getHeader("Client-IP")
            if (!ipAddress) {
                ipAddress = request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For")
            }
            if (!ipAddress) {
                ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr()
            }

            try{
                cifService.resetTryLoginAddInfo(userDetails, ipAddress, session.id)
            }catch (Exception e){
                println "e = "+e
            }

            session.setAttribute("alias", userDetails.userAlias)
            session.setAttribute("fullName", userDetails.firstName + " " + userDetails.lastName)
            session.setAttribute("change", userDetails.forceChangePassword)
            session.setAttribute("userType", userDetails.userType)


            if(userDetails.language != null){
                session[org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver.LOCALE_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME] = new Locale(userDetails.language)
            }
            else{
                session[org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver.LOCALE_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME] = new Locale("id")
            }
            buildMenuList()
            if (params.callback) {
                render"${params.callback} (${[success: true,id: userDetails.id ,change: userDetails.forceChangePassword, username: springSecurityService.authentication.name, fullName: (userDetails.firstName + " " + userDetails.lastName)] as JSON})"
            }
            else {
                render([success: true,id: userDetails.id, change: userDetails.forceChangePassword, username: springSecurityService.authentication.name, fullName: (userDetails.firstName + " " + userDetails.lastName)] as JSON)
            }
        }
        //catch unknown RuntimeException, redirect to Error 500 server Error page
        catch (RuntimeException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e)
            redirect(controller: "error", action: "serverError")
            return
        }
        render([success: true, username: authentication.name] as JSON)
    }
```

but i always get this error log.

```
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login/ajaxSuccess reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
cookies = F866B5D4267DD54163C93FD3DB1EADB5
cifus = null
ERROR org.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver - MissingPropertyException occurred when processing request: [GET] /login/ajaxSuccess
No such property: id for class: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User. Stacktrace follows:
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: id for class: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
        at com.vastpalaso.CorporateUserService.getCurrentCifUser(CorporateUserService.groovy:950) ~[main/:na]
        at accounter.LoginController$$EQ0tGOPB.ajaxSuccess(LoginController.groovy:168) ~[na:na]
        at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter.groovy:64) ~[spring-security-core-3.1.1.jar:na]
        at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.groovy:53) ~[spring-security-core-3.1.1.jar:na]
        at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.groovy:62) ~[spring-security-core-3.1.1.jar:na]
        at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy:58) ~[spring-security-core-3.1.1.jar:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

this is the log

```
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login/authenticate?spring-security-redirect=/login/ajaxSuccess at position 1 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityRequestHolderFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login/authenticate?spring-security-redirect=/login/ajaxSuccess at position 1 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityRequestHolderFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login/authenticate?spring-security-redirect=/login/ajaxSuccess at position 2 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login/authenticate?spring-security-redirect=/login/ajaxSuccess at position 2 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No HttpSession currently exists
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No HttpSession currently exists
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login/authenticate?spring-security-redirect=/login/ajaxSuccess at position 3 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'MutableLogoutFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login/authenticate?spring-security-redirect=/login/ajaxSuccess at position 3 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'MutableLogoutFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/login/authenticate'; against '/logoff'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/login/authenticate'; against '/logoff'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login/authenticate?spring-security-redirect=/login/ajaxSuccess at position 4 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'GrailsUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login/authenticate?spring-security-redirect=/login/ajaxSuccess at position 4 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'GrailsUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
DEBUG org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
DEBUG org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider - User '' not found
DEBUG org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider - User '' not found
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices - Interactive login attempt was unsuccessful.
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices - Interactive login attempt was unsuccessful.
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices - Cancelling cookie
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices - Cancelling cookie
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/login/authfail'; against '/assets/**'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/login/authfail'; against '/assets/**'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/login/authfail'; against '/**/js/**'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/login/authfail'; against '/**/js/**'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/login/authfail'; against '/**/css/**'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/login/authfail'; against '/**/css/**'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/login/authfail'; against '/**/images/**'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/login/authfail'; against '/**/images/**'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/login/authfail'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/login/authfail'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request '/login/authfail' matched by universal pattern '/**'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request '/login/authfail' matched by universal pattern '/**'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login/authfail?login_error=1 at position 1 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityRequestHolderFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login/authfail?login_error=1 at position 1 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityRequestHolderFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login/authfail?login_error=1 at position 2 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login/authfail?login_error=1 at position 2 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No HttpSession currently exists
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No HttpSession currently exists
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login/authfail?login_error=1 at position 3 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'MutableLogoutFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login/authfail?login_error=1 at position 3 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'MutableLogoutFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/login/authfail'; against '/logoff'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/login/authfail'; against '/logoff'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login/authfail?login_error=1 at position 4 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'GrailsUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login/authfail?login_error=1 at position 4 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'GrailsUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login/authfail?login_error=1 at position 5 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login/authfail?login_error=1 at position 5 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login/authfail?login_error=1 at position 6 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'GrailsRememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login/authfail?login_error=1 at position 6 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'GrailsRememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login/authfail?login_error=1 at position 7 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login/authfail?login_error=1 at position 7 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
INFO org.springframework.security.core.SpringSecurityCoreVersion - You are running with Spring Security Core 4.0.3.RELEASE
INFO org.springframework.security.core.SpringSecurityCoreVersion - You are running with Spring Security Core 4.0.3.RELEASE
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login/authfail?login_error=1 at position 8 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login/authfail?login_error=1 at position 8 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login/authfail?login_error=1 at position 9 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login/authfail?login_error=1 at position 9 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /login/authfail?login_error=1; Attributes: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY]
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /login/authfail?login_error=1; Attributes: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY]
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: grails.plugin.springsecurity.authentication.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationToken@f23b441a: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@dc730200: Username: __grails.anonymous.user__; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: false; AccountNonExpired: false; credentialsNonExpired: false; AccountNonLocked: false; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffffe21a: RemoteIpAddress: 192.168.100.9; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: grails.plugin.springsecurity.authentication.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationToken@f23b441a: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@dc730200: Username: __grails.anonymous.user__; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: false; AccountNonExpired: false; credentialsNonExpired: false; AccountNonLocked: false; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffffe21a: RemoteIpAddress: 192.168.100.9; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
DEBUG org.springframework.security.access.hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl - getReachableGrantedAuthorities() - From the roles [ROLE_ANONYMOUS] one can reach [ROLE_ANONYMOUS] in zero or more steps.
DEBUG org.springframework.security.access.hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl - getReachableGrantedAuthorities() - From the roles [ROLE_ANONYMOUS] one can reach [ROLE_ANONYMOUS] in zero or more steps.
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Authorization successful
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Authorization successful
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login/authfail?login_error=1 reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /login/authfail?login_error=1 reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper - Skip invoking on
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper - Skip invoking on
ERROR org.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver - CannotRedirectException occurred when processing request: [GET] /login/authfail - parameters:
login_error: 1
Cannot issue a redirect(..) here. The response has already been committed either by another redirect or by directly writing to the response.. Stacktrace follows:
grails.web.mapping.mvc.exceptions.CannotRedirectException: Cannot issue a redirect(..) here. The response has already been committed either by another redirect or by directly writing to the response.
```

application.groovy

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.vastpalaso.security.User'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'com.vastpalaso.security.UserRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com.vastpalaso.security.Role'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.requestMap.className = 'com.vastpalaso.security.RequestMap'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = 'Requestmap'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    [pattern: '/',               access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/error',          access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/index',          access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/index2.gsp',      access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/shutdown',       access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/assets/**',      access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**/js/**',       access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**/css/**',      access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**/images/**',   access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**/favicon.ico', access: ['permitAll']]
]

grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    [pattern: '/assets/**',      filters: 'none'],
    [pattern: '/**/js/**',       filters: 'none'],
    [pattern: '/**/css/**',      filters: 'none'],
    [pattern: '/**/images/**',   filters: 'none'],
    [pattern: '/**/favicon.ico', filters: 'none'],
    [pattern: '/**',             filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS']
]
```

after i add this below code, my error log become [like this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByvgNTv5gx2dbDdTLUNlWnBvWVU)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643125/springsecurityservice-principal-id-giving-firstname-instead-of-userid

Comment: nope, @vahid i still get a null user... see my update

Comment: it maybe that something else is the issue here `cifus = null` looks like it could not find curent user (logged in)

Comment: Yea..you right..thata why i am confuse why ?

Comment: you will need to look into enabling springsecurity logging - debugging it to see where it goes wrong. Another way a lot more complex would be set up interceptors for springsecurity success/failure events and try to capture more that way. https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-bean-validation-examples/tree/master/src/main/groovy/security. the site has configured additional events to capture those - have a look through there - personally i would start by enabling spring security logging

Comment: @vahid you can see my updated log...i tried to enable the log to debug for springframework

Comment: @vahid its look like i failed to login start from `position 2 of 9`

Comment: look below it `User '' not found`

Comment: @vahid hm...its really strange, why i can get an error like that? as i know, when method `def ajaxSuccess` run, its meaning `username` and `password` where i use to login already right.

Comment: no idea. Ensure user is logged in maybe refer to the interceptor method above ensure success interceptor is definitively hit. Maybe add this ajaxSuccess method to the static Rules block of springSecurity set it to not have any security like images etc in the application.groovy

Comment: @vahid i dont have any security like images or something else in application.groovy, very strange, this error not appear when i try to login with browser

Comment: I am talking about [pattern: '/**/images/**',   access: ['permitAll']], https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-bean-validation-examples/blob/master/grails-app/conf/application.groovy#L26 add a static rule for this controller action for now to permitAll But I don't think the issue is that. The issue relates to user not being authenticated

Comment: @vahid it has been `staticrule`, see this http://www.slideshare.net/burtbeckwith/fun-with-spring-security
start from page 6, my error log like that

Comment: goto slide 7  it binds GrailsUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter with anonymous user yours binds with User '' and fails.. something else not configured right

Comment: @vahid strange, i am using default spring security authentication..maybe this file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39741426/grails-3-with-concurrent-session ?
i add a code like that lastmonth..

Comment: @vahid not this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39741426/grails-3-with-concurrent-session problem... i tried to disable that code, but still get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here:

> **org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider**
>
> - User '' not found

On the [provided link](http://www.slideshare.net/burtbeckwith/fun-with-spring-security)  slide 6 it says `firing organizationFilter`

When you look into [security filters](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html). They are actually those static rules that I mentioned earlier.

so something is of a conflict there and the rule is being bypassed then it attempts to login (with no user credentials).

It is all there in there logs just a matter of interpreting it correctly

Right..
 Comment out this first

```
//grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = 'Requestmap'
```

//Then add

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    [pattern: '/',               access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/error',          access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/index',          access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/index2.gsp',      access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/shutdown',       access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/assets/**',      access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**/js/**',       access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**/css/**',      access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**/images/**',   access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**/favicon.ico', access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/login/ajaxSuccess',       access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/login/ajaxSuccess/**',       access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**/ajaxSuccess/**',       access: ['permitAll']]
]
```

I haved added 3 new rules at the very bottom, the very first one should fix the issue. But I added them just incase. Then the line above it you have changed from annotation to `Requestmap` but then you have `controllerAnnotations.staticRules`  you do need to pay attention to the finer details here.

If you set something to be something else then you need relevant configuration for that.
Please note if you do wish to stick with Requestmap then maybe you need to configure

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
                [pattern: '/',               access: ['permitAll']],
                [pattern: '/something/**',          access: ['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER']],
                [pattern: '/**',          access: ['permitAll']],
]
```

For now I would stick with `securityConfigType: Annotation`

Comment: did you mean my configuration in `application.groovy` ? see my edited post

Comment: yep so you said it was added but I didn't see it /login/ajaxSuccess was not in your map also you are using Requestmap so adding rules to staticAnnotation has no impact if changed from defauls :) try above if you stick with map then try adding those 3 new lines to a new block of config like I have provided for `interceptUrlMap`

Comment: its look like your code works well, but i think i must can get current user from `springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()` after success login like my latest updated post

Comment: not really following you - if that has changed behaviour and you are facing a new problem perhaps worth creating a new issue - do you now go beyond that step 4 ?

Comment: i will create a new issue, which step 4?

Comment: oh i see,, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40310293/cannot-get-getcurrentuser-after-ajaxsuccess :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126928/discussion-between-kiong-lam-and-vahid).